# Uncaught Reference Error using JSONP

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined" when using passing the JSON object into my 'getData' function.

I've reviewed the data type, script type, fiddled with the callback function to no avail. I've tried parsing the returned value in case its text format. Inspecting the element, the error points me to the 'getData' in the JSON object.

I've hard-coded the script below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?callback=getData"></script>
  </head>
```

Returned JSON:

```
(function() { getData({ "type": "success", "value": { "id": 246, "joke": "Chuck Norris? sperm is so badass, he had sex with Nicole Kidman, and 7 months later she prematurely gave birth to a Ford Excursion.", "categories": [] } }); })();
```

JS:

```
function getData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: What is your question? The error seems pretty clear to me: At the moment the script is evaluated, `getData` is not defined. Make sure to define `getData` before you include the other script.

Comment: *"the error points me to the 'getData' in the JSON object"* To be clear: The response is not JSON. It's JavaScript code. Depsite the name "JSONP", it has nothing to do with JSON. You are just including an external JavaScript script (that is dynamically generated).

Comment: Thanks, Felix. Shouldn't using the callback allow me to access data in my getData function?

Comment: Of course. But the function has to exist at the moment it is called. `foo();` will also throw an error if I don't define `foo` before I call it. You are not showing where you are defining the function, but the error makes it clear that it is *not* before the external script.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML in your question only has one `<script>` element (to load the JSONP program).

While you have shown the JS to define `getData`, you haven't loaded into your HTML (and you need to do that, using another `<script>` element) before you load the JSONP program that depends on it).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function getData(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?callback=getData"></script>
</head>
```